# Not able to access server running on linux terminal from browser in chromeos

Tags: http, portforwarding, chromebook

I have an http server running on the linux terminal VM in chromeos on port 5555. I have the port forwarding set up so that TCP on port 5555 can go to the linux terminal. When I visit `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, or the chromebook's private IP address from the chromebook, nothing happens and no request is sent. When I visit the chromebook's ip from another device, I see the request show up in the server logs, but no data is sent back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems for accessing the local linux environment from the chromeos browser, you should use "penguin.local" (where penguin is the name of the linux container) rather than "localhost". So, http://penguin.local:5555 should get a connection to your listener in the linux environment, assuming it's listening on 5555. You can see what ports have listeners by running "netstat -na |grep tcp" . If you have a listener on 5555, it should show "0.0.0.0:5555             0.0.0.0:*" in the 4th and 5th columns.